# Angular 2 is not making http call from browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, typescript, angular, angular2-http

I have a problem in angular 2 in typescript that browser is not making HTTP Call. I dont see any HTTp call in network section in browser.
the angular code works when i dont have any http call in service and it brings data when i use HTTP it doenst make any http request

Following is my code.

```
<script src="~/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/system.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/router.dev.js"></script>
```

**SERVICE :**

```
    import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private _authPath = 'http://api/Auth';
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    getAuthSettings() {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            return this.http.get(this._authPath).toPromise().then((val: Response) => resolve(val.text()));

        });
    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

**main MODULE** :

```
    import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({

    selector: "main-app",
    template: "{{title}}",
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public title: string = '';
    constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        //this.title = "aaa";
        this._authService.getAuthSettings().then((val: string) => {
            this.title = val;

        });
        //this._authService.getAuthSettings().subscribe((val: string) => this.title = val)
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont see any HTTP call in network section in browser.

There might be some filters preventing you from seeing it. To be sure update the code as follows:

```
 console.log('starting');
 this._authService.getAuthSettings()
     .then((val: string) => {
        this.title = val;
        console.log('success');
     },() => console.log('fail'));
 console.log('waiting');
```

And see which logs happen. Hopefully it helps. Sorry if it doesn't

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I set up cors in my asp core app, I call the url with postman and it gives me a json. When I try to call from the service it returns nothing. I tried with your code, and it only shows 'waiting'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030613/asp-net-core-api-cors-for-angular2-app